# Method of inserting into a map in c++11 and c++17?

Tags: c++, stl

I created a map using

```cpp
std::map<long,std::vector<long> > indices
```

When trying to insert a key and vector element with

```cpp
indices.insert(std::pair<long,std::vector<long> >(0,{0,1,2}));
```

I get huge lines of error ending with

```
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_map.h:685:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
Main.cpp:44:66: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
     indices.insert(std::pair<long,std::vector<long> > (0,{0,1,2}));
```

if during compilation I do

```
g++ Main.cpp -std=c++17
```

However it compiles without any error with

```
g++ Main.cpp -std=c++11
```

Is the procedure different in c++17 ? If yes, what is it?
Or am I missing something?

Comment: You should be using `std::pair<const long,std::vector<long> >`.  The first element of the pair (`value_type`) is a const object.

Comment: Still shows the same error if I compile with `-std=c++17`

Comment: Cannot reproduce https://godbolt.org/z/MCEx9r

Comment: Not sure what I am doing wrong then, compiler error?

Comment: Probably an error on the line above the one you posted. These locations are not always exact

Comment: This may be some interaction between the mingw compiler and [`#include "bits/stdc++.h"'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/5231607).

Comment: This question could be clearer if it had [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Your above `insert(std::pair<long,std::vector<long> >(0,{0,1,2}))` looks fine. It should work if it is GNU C++ 17 I think as it worked in my case.

I think this following would also work now in C++17,

```
indices.insert({ {0},{{0,1,2}} });
```

C++ 17 has introduced a new overload to permit `insert( { {key}, {value, args} } )` syntax.